# Does Salesforce allow you to specify which exceptions a method can throw?

Tags: salesforce

We all know that Java allows you to specify in a method signature which exceptions might be thrown by that method. Does Salesforce support a similar approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. `throws` is not even a [reserved keyword](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_reserved_words.htm).

You can have try-catch-finally but some exceptions (like governor limits) or even `System.assert(false);` can't be caught.

So: expect the worst or if you want to hold some kind of "contract" with calling classes - you can still make an interface...

Comment: Unfortunately SaleForce has a lot of limits that we have to live with. Thank you